# When i update my info the session is destroyed if i remove destroy session then the message does not vanish on refresh

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-state

When I update my info the session is destroyed. If I remove destroy session then the message does not vanish on refresh

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['loginfail'])){
    $msg = $_SESSION['loginfail'];
    ?>  
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <?php echo $msg;?>
    </div>
<?php
} 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorta curious where the `session_start();` code is?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to destroy the whole session if you only want to delete the message from the session

a simple

```
unset($_SESSION['loginfail']);
```

will do it